# Find difference when comparing lists of sets

Tags: python, list, set, compare

How do I find the difference of two lists that contains sets?

```
List 1:
    [{0, 1, 3, 9}, {2, 5, 6}, {8, 4}]
List 2:
    [{6, 7, 8, 9}]
```

**Result should be:**

```
[{7}]
```

Comment: I don't understand 100%, but why is 9 in the result if it is in list 1?

Comment: So 9 should not be there, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Create two sets and fill them with values from your lists. Then the desired result is simple substraction.

```
l1 = [{0, 1, 3, 9}, {2, 5, 6}, {8, 4}]
l2 = [{6, 7, 8, 9}]

s1 = set()
for i in l1:
    s1.update(i)

s2 = set()
for i in l2:
    s2.update(i)

print(s2 - s1)
# {7}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can just flatten the list1, then find the differences:

```
>>> l1 = [{0, 1, 3, 9}, {2, 5, 6}, {8, 4}]
>>> l2 = [{6, 7, 8, 9}]
>>> l3 = [x for y in l1 for x in y]
>>> l3
[0, 9, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 4]
>>> l4 = [set(i for i in l2[0] if i not in l3)]
>>> l4
[set([7])]
```